# MissingReferenceException: Error after destroying a moving game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game some objects move every few seconds and others don't. I have created a the method below to handle the movement of moving objects.

```
private IEnumerator moveObject(GameObject movingObject, float posX, float duration) {
if(movingObject != null) {
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    Vector3 startPos = movingObject.transform.position;
    Vector3 endpos = new Vector3(posX, objectPositionY, camera.nearClipPlane);//hole.transform.position;

    while(movingObject != null && elapsedTime < duration) {
        movingObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endpos, elapsedTime / duration);
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
}
```

Also I destroy the moving objects using the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < holeObjects.Count; i++) {
    Debug.Log ("countingholeobjectindex"+ i );

    if (col.gameObject.Equals (holeObjects [i].getHoleObject ())) {
       Debug.Log ("condition satisfied!" );

       foreach( HoleObjectSetup holeItem in holeObjects )
       {
          if (holeItem.getHoleObjectType () == HoleObjectSetup.HoleObjectType.moving) {
          int holeItemIndex = holeObjects.IndexOf(holeItem);
          holeItem.StopAllCoroutines();
          holeItem.DestroyHoleObject ();

          //holeObjects.RemoveAll(item=>item==null);
          //holeObjects.RemoveAt(holeItemIndex);

       }
    }
}
```

Any time I destroy a movingObject (mostly, when it's moving), I get the error

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
```

pointing to the line

```
movingObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endpos, elapsedTime / duration);
```

in the `movingObject` method (provided above). I tried adding another nullity check to surround the contents of the while loop, but that made Unity3d unresponsive, leaving me with the only option of force quitting. How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**
`movingObject` is called in the coroutine below:

```
private IEnumerator MovementLogic(GameObject movingObject)
{
    // keep going until deactivated or disabled
    float currentPos = movingObject.transform.position.x;
    while(filledPositions.Contains(currentPos))
    {
        float newPos = getNextPos(currentPos);
                  if(freePositions.Contains(newPos))
            {
                freePositions.Add (currentPos);
                filledPositions.Remove (currentPos);
                freePositions.Remove (newPos);
                filledPositions.Add (newPos);

                yield return moveObject(movingObject, newPos, movementDuration);

                //update positions
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(movementDelay);
                currentPos = newPos;

            }
            else
            {
                // if a valid hole wasn't found, try the other direction next frame
                ReverseDirection();
            }
        }

    yield return null;
    //}
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The code for `DestroyHoleObject()` which is in `HoleObjectSetup` is:

```
    public void DestroyHoleObject   ()  {
    Destroy (currentHoleObject);
}
```

and

```
    public void createHoleObjectType    (GameObject holeObject, HoleObjectType holeObjectType, Vector3 holeObjectPosition, bool isCollider2DEnabled)    {

    currentHoleObject = (GameObject)Instantiate (holeObject, holeObjectPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    setHoleObjectType (holeObjectType);

}
```

Comment: Where is that movement coroutine located? Are you actually stopping it before you destroy the object?

Comment: A quick advice: Use `update()` method to move objects instead of `while`. And can you post the stack trace of exception along

Comment: @GunnarB. I just updated the question. Yes, I stop the coroutines before destroying the object.

Comment: "moveObject" must be called "MoveObject".

Comment: "destroyHoleObject" must be called "DestroyHoleObject"

Comment: @Nullititiousness, you **don't include the code** for "DestroyHoleObject".  How can you expect anyone to help dude??

Comment: @JoeBlow: I just updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the problem by adding

```
Debug.Log
```

statements everywhere.  It will take a few seconds to find out the exact point in the cycle that is causing problems.

Secondly,

Sometimes a cheap solution to these problems is, use

```
DestroyImmediate
```

rather than

```
Destroy
```

This might give you a quick fix.

Thirdly. Be more sophisticated about coroutines:

Something like ..

```
void OnEnable()
 {
 Debug.Log("enable .."); 
 }

void OnDisable()
 {
 StopCoroutine("Whatever");
 .. or perhaps ..
 StopAllCoroutines();
 }
```

Moreover, ideally you should "handle it manually".

Consider the object you are getting rid of.

**That class, should have a function something like this:**

```
void BeingDestroyed()
 {
 .. carefully write your own code here to shut down the object ..
 }
```

... and actually **call that explicitly** when you are about to destroy it.

It's not that easy to add, destroy stuff in games.  It's often very complex.

Could be the object destroys itself: perform any needed shutdown code, wait a frame or two if that is relevant to you, remove from any lists, and then "destroy self".

You can't just "leave coroutines alone": you have to manage them carefully by hand.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestions. I had already tried the first suggestion, which helped me find out that error occurs during the movement. Secondly, `DestroyImmediate` produced the error `Destroying GameObjects immediately is not permitted during physics trigger/contact, animation event callbacks or OnValidate. You must use Destroy instead.
UnityEngine.Object:DestroyImmediate(Object)`. I am trying to find a way to implement your third suggestion.

Comment: Actually, the fourth worked. Thanks. Just one more thing, when I check the `holeObjects.Count` it still recognises the same number of objects before the destruction. How and where will be an appropriate place to remove them from the `holeObjects` list?

Comment: note that a common thing is you have to skip a frame or two (using 'yield return null` of course), after destroying stuff, to "allow the system to get rid of everything".  it's a tricky business.